# Android how to randomly swap button positions?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a `LinearLayout` with 9 `Buttons`, I would like to swap their positions randomly with each other. I tried something but it didn't seem to work,here is what i tried , I know this is not random but I would like to get random:

```
float pos0,pos1,pos2,pos3,pos4,pos5,pos6,pos7,pos8,pos9;            
float place1,place2,place3,place4,place5,place6,place7,place8,place9;

pos0=btn0.getX();

                pos1=btn1.getX();
                pos2=btn2.getX();
                pos3=btn3.getX();
                pos4=btn4.getX();
                pos5=btn5.getX();
                pos6=btn6.getX();
                pos7=btn7.getX();
                pos8=btn8.getX();
                pos9=btn9.getX();

                float [] arrange1 = {
                        pos0,pos1,pos2,pos3,pos4,pos5,pos6,pos7,pos8,pos9
                };

                float [] arrange2 = {
                        pos0,pos1,pos2,pos3,pos4,pos5,pos6,pos7,pos8,pos9
                };

                for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                    place1=random(arrange1);
                    place2=random2(arrange2);

                    if(place1==place2){
                        place1=pos0;
                        place2=pos9;
                    }

                    while(place1!=place2){
                    if(i==1){
                        btn0.setX(place2);
                        btn1.setX(place1);
                    }

                    if(i==2){
                        btn2.setX(place2);
                        btn3.setX(place1);
                    }

                    if(i==3){
                        btn4.setX(place2);
                        btn5.setX(place1);
                    }

                    if(i==4){
                        btn6.setX(place2);
                        btn7.setX(place1);
                    }

                    if(i==5){
                        btn8.setX(place2);
                        btn9.setX(place1);
                    }

                    if(i==6){
                        btn0.setX(place2);
                        btn2.setX(place1);
                    }

                    if(i==7){
                        btn2.setX(place2);
                        btn7.setX(place1);
                    }

                    if(i==8){
                        btn9.setX(place2);
                        btn1.setX(place1);
                    }

                    if(i==9){
                        btn4.setX(place2);
                        btn2.setX(place1);
                    }   

                    }

                }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put all the buttons in an ArrayList, then, use Math.Random to randomly pick one of the buttons and place it on the screen, remove said button from ArrayList, then repeat. This way, you could rearrange without destroying. Prior to the rearrangement, I would go to each button, and setVisible(false) to prevent mixups.

If that's too much work, I saw in another response, you asked if you can change the labels of a button. Absolutely! And that's actually a much better idea. I would've responded over there, but I don't have a high enough rating to comment yet.

Anyways, if you are doing the renaming option, you could do something along the lines of...

```
public void rearrange()
   {

      int[] nums = new int[10];

      int holder;

      Random r = new Random();

      boolean doesItMatch = true;

      holder = r.nextInt(10);

      for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
      {

         nums[j] = 10;

      }

      //^^This for loop is just to give them a value to start with so they won't be null. 
      //I assume the buttons will already have values by the time it's time to scramble

      for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {

         do
         {

            doesItMatch = false;

            for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
            {

               if(nums[k] == holder)
               {

                  doesItMatch = true;
                  holder = r.nextInt(10);
                  k = 10;

               }

            }

         }while(doesItMatch);

         nums[i] = holder;
         r.nextInt(10);

      }

   }
```

Then, after you do that, just link a name to a number and start pasting. For example, let's imagine Johnny goes on 1, Tiffy goes on 2, and Michael goes on 3, etc. Just search for the one that has a 1 and replace with Johnny, 2 with Tiffy, etc. I recommend you make them invisible for the split second that you do put the number values there so that they don't flash back and forth between numbers. Or you could extend the button class/add an attribute to the button class that gives them an index. Then, everything should work out quite nicely!

Answer (score 0):

You can not change order of views in LinearLayout. You can remove views and add them back to different position with

```
ViewGroup.addView (View child, int index)
```

This is not very efficient of course.

When your buttons look all the same it is probably much easier just to change labels on them.

Comment: is it possible to change ids and labels? because I have some functions ,and also But what I am trying to do is if button 1 is at 10.1,button 2 is at 14.1 and button 3 is at 18.1 I would like to randomly swap the positions that is when the user scores point the button s jumble and say button 1 interchanges positions with button 2 and button 2 instead of button 3 etc... –

Comment: Yes, of course you can change view labels. It is also possible to change view id-s but I dont recommend doing that. Instead use setTag and getTag methods to associate whatever info you need with your buttons.